# Depth map with Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

Is it possible to get two images from the Raspberry Pi camera mounted on a remote controlled bot and have them sent to a computer through Wi-Fi and process the images in the computer to generate a depth map?

All this is to be done in a very short time so that the robot can be helped with its locomotion without making it completely autonomous.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. This is a form of [stereo vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_stereo_vision). You will need an accurate model of how the robot moved between frames. Then you can use stereo vision techniques to calculate the disparity.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using the Compute Module IO board for my undergraduate project and up to now, the best I can come up with is a refresh rate of 2Hz implemented using c++.

Mr. David Barker at Argon design was [able to implement it](http://www.argondesign.com/case-studies/2014/oct/21/stereo-depth-perception-raspberry-pi/) at 1Hz using C and 12 frames per second by using machine language on the video core.

Mr. Nalan Karunanayake was [able to implement stereo vision](https://computervision-nalan.blogspot.com/2015/05/stereo-vision-using-raspberry-pi.html) using a model B+ and two usb webcams set at 10 frames per second in c++.

I read an IEEE paper if I am remembering it correctly being able to sync both camera modules using v4l2 drivers ([Raspberry PI Based Stereo Vision For Small Size ASVs](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6741334)<sup>†</sup>).

<sup>† Requires IEEE Xplore subscription or purchase.</sup>